# How to write a function with move-only attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference

I have a type that is move-only, copy is forbidden. 
I want to pass it in some system, but I'm not sure which kind of signature to use for the functions taking that type in parameter. The objects of this type have to be moved into the system, no copy should be ever done.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( std::string name ) : m_name( std::move( name ) ){}
    Foo( Foo&& other ) : m_name( std::move( other.m_name ) ){}
    Foo& operator=( Foo&& other ){ m_name = std::move( other.m_name ); }

    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
    // ...
private:
    Foo( const Foo& ) ;//= delete;
    Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) ;//= delete;
    // ...

    std::string m_name;
};

class Bar
{
public:

    void add( Foo foo )  // (1)
        // or...
    void add( Foo&& foo ) // (2)
    {
        m_foos.emplace_back( std::move(foo) ); // if add was template I should use std::forward?
    }


private:
    std::vector<Foo> m_foos;
};

void test()
{
    Bar bar;
    bar.add( Foo("hello") );

    Foo foo("world");
    bar.add( std::move(foo) );
}
```

(Both signatures compile in VS2012, assuming I'm moving the objects)

Which signature between 1 and 2 should be the preferred?

It looks like both works but I think there have to be differences...

Comment: Signature one wouldn't compile since you can't copy `Foo`s. You should use (2).

Comment: @SethCarnegie yes, it would compile.

Comment: @SethCarnegie what if he called it using an rvalue-ref? Like in his last example line.

Comment: @SethCarnegie It works in VS2012, when you move the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signature #1 will cost 2 move constructions when moving from an xvalue, whereas signature #2 will cost just 1 move construction from xvalues.  Therefore #2 sounds better to me.  But as long as move construction is cheap, either signature will get the job done.  Do you want:

1. Really fast, or
2. Twice as fast as really fast?

:-)

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If you want to move the object into the function, take it by value. The compiler will do the move itself, and you'll clearly document to the caller that the function moves the argument passed. If you use the second, the function *may or may not* move the argument, even though the caller will have to use `std::move(foo)`. That can be very confusing.

If you don't want to move the object into the function, take an lvalue reference. Make it const if the function does not mutate, non-const if it mutates.

Comment: I really want to move the object. The semantic of the object's type should really require it because copying is non-sense (like std::thread or similar types). I'll add some precisions.

Comment: @Klaim then signature #1 is the way to go.

Comment: Can you add an explaination of why in 2) the function may or may not move the argument, please? I'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: @Klaim `void f(foo&&) {}` will not move the argument. However `void f(foo) {}` will. What I mean is that the first signature forces that move, but the second gives leeway to the implementation.